# how to get rid of syntax error in try-catch block in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using below code in controller.js file. When running in local machine the  code is running finr but while running in aws ec2 machine I am getting error. Can you please help me in this issue?

```
query(request_body,(results,error) =>{
      if (error){
        return res.status(404).json(error);
      }
      if (results){
        try{
              if (results.Items.length == 0 ) {
                error_msg = {"message":"No record found for  given search criteria"};
                return res.status(404).json(error_msg)
              } else {
                return res.status(200).json(results)
              }
           } 
        catch { 
          return res.status(200).json(results)
        }
      }       
    }
  )
```

error:

```
home/ubuntu/node-temp/api/src/user.controller.js:30
        catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node-temp/api/src/user.router.js:2:78)
```

Comment: Update your node version, or write something like `catch(_error) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    // code
} catch {

}
```

This is called **[optional catch binding](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-catch-binding)**.

Update your node version to at least [10.3.0](https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding) or change your code to something like:

```
try {
     // code
} catch (_unused) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try catch syntax look like this

```
try {
   ...stuff 

} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

so it would look like this

```
query(request_body,(results,error) =>{
      if (error){
        return res.status(404).json(error);
      }
      if (results){
        try{
              if (results.Items.length == 0 ) {
                error_msg = {"message":"No record found for  given search criteria"};
                return res.status(404).json(error_msg)
              } else {
                return res.status(200).json(results)
              }
           } 
        catch (error) { 
          return res.status(200).json(results)
        }
      }       
    }
  )
```